# How to save multiple MySQL queries in a json array?

Tags: php, json

I have a website with an ajax 'POST' method that sends a data id to a php file. According to the id received, appropriate MySQL queries are received from the database and put into a JSON array.

Archive.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["id"])){ //data received from the html POST method 

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    if(is_numeric($id) == TRUE){
        $query="SELECT * FROM TestDataBase.usr WHERE idusr =" . $id;
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }else if(is_numeric($id) == FALSE && $id != ""){
        $query="SELECT * FROM TestDataBase.usr WHERE INSTR(name,'" . $id ."')";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
    $i=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $data["num"] = $i;

            $i += 1;
            $data["idusr"] = $row["idusr"];
            $data["name"] = $row["name"];
            $data["surname"] = $row["surname"];
        }


    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Using MySQL `INSTR` method, I parse all the queries containing the `id` into a `$data` array and then encode it as json, but for some reason only last query in the table is sent back to the html file. How would it be possible to add multiple queries into the json array instead of one? Thanks!

Comment: You are overwriting `$data` everytime you loop. So it will only hold 1 item.

Comment: @Michel is there a way to save multiple `$data` arrays in one two-dimensional array? I am not really sure if it would be able to be encoded as json though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a twodimensional array from your results, you have to add an array to an array:

```
  $data=[]; // <-- create empty array to hold the results      

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     //NOW push all elements in an array into $data:

     $data[]= // <-- push new value in $data = array
       [
        'num' => $i,
        'idusr' => $row['idusr'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'surname' => $row['surname']
       ];
     $i += 1;
    }


    echo json_encode($data);
```